# How to search in Artifactory Repo sub folder only using curl

Tags: curl, artifactory

So I previously had a script to search for folders in my Artifactory repositories for a certain property.

```
curl -i -X GET "${ARTIFACTORY_URI}/api/search/prop?my-prop=aaa&repos=my-repo
```

So far so good. The way I deployed my artifacts was that I placed them in sub folders and each of the sub folders got assigned the property my-prop. Then when I ran this command, I got back a list of the sub folders that satisfied my search criteria. This worked because the sub folders where all directly inside the repo my-repo.

However now we have had to do some restructuring of the Artifactory. Now the sub folders that I'm trying to list are located in a sub folder inside a sub folder inside the repo. My command still works, but it returns all the sub folders.

For example consider this:

```
my-repo:
   * folder1
      + folder1-1
         - folder1-1-1 (my-prop=aaa)
         - folder1-1-2 (my-prop=bbb)
      + folder1-2
         - folder1-2-1 (my-prop=aaa)
   * folder2
      + folder2-1
         - folder2-1-1 (my-prop=aaa)
```

So what I get now when searching for my-prop=aaa using the same command is folder1-1-1, folder1-2-1 and folder2-1-1. But what I want to do is limit the search to the sub-sub-folder folder1-1. I tried to simply add the path to the `repos`  parameter but it doesn't work.

```
curl -i -X GET "${ARTIFACTORY_URI}/api/search/prop?my-prop=aaa&repos=my-repo/folder1/folder1-1
```

So my question is how would one do that? The Artifactory website being the train wreck that it is, is of course not very helpful. Is there an additional folder/path parameter that I can use? I want to note, that I am working on an incredibly restrictive customer system and do not have access to the JFrog CLI tool, so I've got to do everything using curl and wget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [AQL (Artifactory Query Language)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)) for that.

For your example, use something like:

```
curl -X POST "${ARTIFACTORY_URI}/api/search/aql" \
     -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
     --data 'items.find({"repo":"my-repo","@my-prop":"aaa","path":"folder1","type":"folder"})'
```

This will do a search in `my-repo` for *folders* with the given property and under the exact path `folder1`. You can use other operators, like `$match`, if the path should be a pattern instead of an exact match.

For the full AQL syntax and guidelines, see: [Artifactory Query Language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language)

Comment: Tried it, it only returned empty arrays, so I gradually fiddled around with the parameters my-prop and path and eventually removed them altogether. Then it returns obviously everything that's in the repository. But what I'm trying to do is downloading artifacts that are lumped together in a folder, that's why I have set my properties on the folder level, not on the individual files. And therefore I'm actually trying to get a list of eligible folders before actually downloading them. But your approach seems to only care about file levels, but I'm working on folders

Comment: Ha, I missed that part in your question, that the properties are on the folders... Sorry for that... Items have an additional field called "type" which is either "file" or "folder". By default Artifactory searches for files, unless asked  otherwise... I will update my answer.

Comment: Happy to help (-:  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related to this question and I thought I would add my solution here

So I was trying to query whether an artifact for a given version exists in this structure

```
repoName
- folderA
  - folderA0
    - 0.0.1.zip
    - 0.0.2.zip
    ...
  - folderA1
    - 0.0.1.zip
    - 0.0.2.zip
    ...
- folderB
  - folderB1
    ...
```

With this `curl` command I was able to narrow down to a given artifact:

```
curl -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -X POST "${ARTIFACTORY_URI}/api/search/aql" -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data 'items.find({"repo":"repoName","path":"folderA/folderA0","name":"0.0.1.zip","type":"file"})'
```

The output I got looked like this, which I can then parse with a JSON parser (`jq`, a programming language library)

```
{
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "repoName",
  "path" : "folderA/folderA0",
  "name" : "0.0.1.zip",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 75069478,
  "created" : "2022-10-24T17:22:10.260Z",
  "created_by" : "USER",
  "modified" : "2022-10-24T17:22:09.401Z",
  "modified_by" : "USER",
  "updated" : "2022-10-24T17:22:10.261Z"
} ],
"range" : {
  "start_pos" : 0,
  "end_pos" : 1,
  "total" : 1
}
}
```

If the artifact did not exist, I got:

```
{
"results" : [  ],
"range" : {
  "start_pos" : 0,
  "end_pos" : 0,
  "total" : 0
}
}
```